# How to get the no of matched occurrences using grep command in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If we use **grep -c** option it will give you the each occurrences only once per line. But I need the total no of matched occurrences not line count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this 
grep -o pattern path | wc -l

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-o` flag to output only the matched part and then pipe it to `wc -w` to get word count.

Eg: `ls ~ | grep -o pattern | wc -w`

Comment: @SureshKumar: I'm glad to know that, welcome to SO. It is recommended that you upvote/accept the answer which solved your problem so that any other user facing similar issue can try that answer.